# AWS Cassandra nodejs - strange results

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cassandra, cql

I'm looking to work with cassandra using cassandra-driver in nodejs.

When I execute a simple query like this:

```js
  const results = await chatDbClient.execute('SELECT * FROM chat_db.messages LIMIT 5');
  return results.rows;
```

I receive the following results:

```sh
Row from Keyspaces Row {
  user_from: [Long],
  user_to: [Long],
  message_id: [TimeUuid],
  body: 'c'
}
[
  Row {
    user_from: Long { low: 1, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    user_to: Long { low: 2, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    message_id: TimeUuid {
      buffer: <Buffer f0 c2 49 b1 fd a4 11 ea 8b 02 85 9f 38 c2 63 74>
    },
    body: 'c'
  },
  Row {
    user_from: Long { low: 1, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    user_to: Long { low: 2, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    message_id: TimeUuid {
      buffer: <Buffer f0 c2 22 a3 fd a4 11 ea bc 5e cb 7d 37 47 a0 82>
    },
    body: 'f'
  },
  Row {
    user_from: Long { low: 1, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    user_to: Long { low: 2, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    message_id: TimeUuid {
      buffer: <Buffer f0 c2 22 a2 fd a4 11 ea bc 5e cb 7d 37 47 a0 82>
    },
    body: 'e'
  },
  Row {
    user_from: Long { low: 1, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    user_to: Long { low: 2, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    message_id: TimeUuid {
      buffer: <Buffer f0 c1 fb 95 fd a4 11 ea a3 0f 3b e9 2e a5 73 87>
    },
    body: 'd'
  },
  Row {
    user_from: Long { low: 1, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    user_to: Long { low: 2, high: 0, unsigned: false },
    message_id: TimeUuid {
      buffer: <Buffer f0 c1 fb 94 fd a4 11 ea a3 0f 3b e9 2e a5 73 87>
    },
    body: 'm'
  }
]
```

But if I execute the query directly from aws dashboard for testing purpose I receive this:

[image]

Why in my app the result has such a strange format?

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 1):

problem solved, to read the data is quite sufficient to use: toString()

`results.rows[i].user_to.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your app

```js
console.log(result.rows[0].timeid instanceof TimeUuid);
```

Comment: If I import the instance of TimeUuid from cassandra driver the results is: true